# AJAX not reading PHP JSON echo

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a simple jQuery AJAX request that submits user input from a text box to a PHP file. Here's the code for it:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

The PHP file basically logs the user in. Everything worked fine until I added "`dataType: 'json'`" to my AJAX request. Now, whenever I click my submit button, nothing logs. Here is my PHP file:

```
<?php
include 'dbcon.php';

if ( isset( $_POST['text_login_username'], $_POST['text_login_password'] ) ) {
    $loginResult = array();
    $dbcon = getConnection();
    $userName = mysqli_real_escape_string( $dbcon, $_POST['text_login_username'] );
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string( $dbcon, $_POST['text_login_password'] );
    $loginQuery = "SELECT * FROM userData WHERE userName='$userName' AND userPassword='$password'";
    $queryResult = mysqli_query( $dbcon, $loginQuery );
    $legalRows = mysqli_num_rows( $result );
    if ( $legalRows == 1 ) {
       $loginResult['allClear']=0;  
    } else {
       $loginResult['allClear']=1;
    }

    echo json_encode( $loginResult );
}
?>
```

AJAX file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('form.loginSubmit').on('submit',function(){


    var that = $(this),
        url=that.attr('action'),
        type=that.attr('method'),
        data={};

    that.find('[name]').each(function(index,value){ 
        var that=$(this), 
            name=that.attr('name'); 
            value=that.val(); 
            data[name]=value;
    });


    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        contenType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error)
        {
            console.log("test");
        }


    });

return false;

});


});
```

I can assure that the proper links to files, posts, etc. are set up properly, because this works until I try to send out the `json_encode` variable. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

~Carpetfizz

UPDATE: I added an `error:` setting to my AJAX call, and it runs whenever I submit.

UPDATE: Check out my answer. This was the solution for me.

Comment: Plain text password :(

Comment: have you tried `header('Content-type: application/json');`?

Comment: @cryocide No I have not, where exactly  do I put it?

Comment: depending on what browser you are using, might need to include a header with a certain configuration, sometimes IE requires it.

Comment: Have you run the php file separately with dummy variables to assure that you're getting true json returned to client? Or are you seeing good json returned on the console? Would you consider adding a .fail to the ajax to see what happens?

Comment: the dataType refers to the request method, the $_GET/$_POST cannot retrieve your data, it should be php://input, what are you sending a json object? and what are expecting as response?

Comment: please use one more option of ajax method:'POST'

Comment: call header() before any output is sent (i.e. before you `echo` anything).kuldeep is probably spot on with setting the AJAX method, but that wouldn't explain why it worked before

Comment: Thanks for the replies. `header()` didn't work. Also, `type` is the method that is attributed in HTML, so wouldn't that take care of it?

Comment: @jerjer, thanks but this did not work either.

Comment: can you try print_r ($_POST);

Comment: if no results the request params are now in the php://input, you read it like $params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); $username = $params['text_login_username'];

Comment: Nothing happens when I do `print_r($POST);`

Comment: @Carpetfizz Run my code in localhost and compare with your file

Comment: try with var_dump($_POST); var_dump($_GET); inside php file.

Comment: @sensorario what does that do ?

Comment: Show you the content of $_POST and $_GET. I wrote it becouse you still search in $_POST but maybe you are not sending data in the suspected way.

Answer (score 1):

Check this code

**demo.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<title>jQuery AJAX Call to PHP Script with JSON Return</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px}
.the-return {background: #f0f0f0; padding: 10px; margin-top: 15px}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function(){
    $(".js-ajax-php-json").submit(function(){
        var data = {
            "action": "test"
        };
        data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "response.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                $(".the-return").html(
                    "Favorite beverage: " + data["favorite_beverage"] + "<br />Favorite restaurant: " + data["favorite_restaurant"] + "<br />Gender: " + data["gender"] + "<br />JSON: " + data["json"]
                );

                alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><b>jQuery AJAX Call to PHP Script with JSON Return</b></p>
<form action="return.php" class="js-ajax-php-json" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <input type="text" name="favorite_beverage" value="" placeholder="Favorite restaurant" />
  <input type="text" name="favorite_restaurant" value="" placeholder="Favorite beverage" />
  <select name="gender">
    <option value="male">Male</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit form"  />
</form>
<div class="the-return">
  [HTML is replaced when successful.]
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**return.php**

```
<?php
if (is_ajax()) {
    if (isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"])) { //Checks if action value exists
        $action = $_POST["action"];
        switch($action) { //Switch case for value of action
            case "test": test(); break;
        }
    }
}

//Function to check if the request is an AJAX request
function is_ajax() {
    return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}

function test(){
    $return = $_POST;

    //Do what you need to do with the info. The following are some examples.
    //if ($return["favorite_beverage"] == ""){
    //  $return["favorite_beverage"] = "Coke";
    //}
    //$return["favorite_restaurant"] = "McDonald's";

    $return["json"] = json_encode($return);
    echo json_encode($return);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for doing this, I will definitely take a look.

Comment: Awesome bit of code, but in the html file it calls response.php and the answer tells us to call it return.php - Took me a sec to figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: Your example says to create 2 files - return.php and demo.html however in demo.html, the ajax code calls "response.php" ` $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "response.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(data) `

Comment: @Adam Sorry its my mistake. now i can modified my file name called demo.php. now you check it your sel. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1.- Use header content-type in your PHP code:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

2.- Use content-type header in your jQuery ajax code:

```
contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8'
```

3.- Check if your ajax jQuery code is POST or GET( default: get ):

```
type: "post"
```

4.- Print JSON in your PHP:

```
if( array_key_exists("text_login_username",$_POST) AND array_key_exists("text_login_password",$_POST) )
{
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    /**
    *   Create link
    */
    $link = getConnection(); /* user function */
    /**
    * Default value for result
    */
    $result = array(
        "allClear"  =>  1
    );
    /**
    *   first arg is connection
    *   mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )
    */
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string( $link , $_POST["text_login_username"] );
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string( $link , $_POST["text_login_password"] );
    
    /**
    *   Select "1" is best way with LIMIT; you dont need all fields... ¬¬ bad way...
    **/
    $source = mysqli_query( $link , "SELECT 1 FROM userData WHERE userData.userName='$username' AND userData.userPassword='$password' LIMIT 1" , MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT  );
    /**
    * count
    */
    if( mysqli_num_rows( $source ) == 1 )
    {
        $result["allClear"] = 0;
    }
    /**
    *   print json
    */
    echo json_encode( $result );
    /**
    *   prevent others prints
    */
    exit;
}
```

5.- Use **[array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-key-exists.php)** to verified if exists key in array

```
bool array_key_exists( mixed $key , array $search )
```

6.- Use this **$.ajax** code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "json.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {
        text_login_username  : "xxxx",
        text_login_password  : "xxx"
    },
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response)
    {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Make sure that your data variable in JS has the correct syntax of a JS object. More info about JSON objects [here](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp)

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please show me what the data variable looks like in your JS code

Comment: Your data variable isn't in the correct format. It needs to be a JSON object

Comment: Do you mean my PHP variable or my Javascript variable?

Comment: Hm it seems to be correct, when I `console.log(data)`, I get `Object {text_login_username: "carpetfizz", text_login_password: "test"}`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? Add to your server script.

My json_encode returned nothing also until I added this when I upgraded my PHP version. Its got to do with json_encode only working on UTF-8

```
mysqli_query($dbcon, "SET NAMES utf8");
```

I also added this to the top of the script...

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
```

Answer (score -2):

The solution was weird. There was something wrong with `mysqli_num_rows`. I just did this instead.

```
$legalRows=$queryResult->num_rows;
```

It works fine. Thanks for all the great answers. I definitely learned some new things that I will be implementing.

Comment: this should work too right? `mysqli_num_rows( $queryResult );`